# How not to persist certain values ​in redux persist?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have next redux persist config

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['common', 'script', 'setting', 'viewer', 'home']
};
```

in every component I have loading indicator with true flag, but because of redux persist
after first load I all time get false.
How can I say redux persist dont touch some values in reducer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native + redux-persist: how to ignore keys (blacklist)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197502/react-native-redux-persist-how-to-ignore-keys-blacklist)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197502/react-native-redux-persist-how-to-ignore-keys-blacklist/41203037#41203037][link]